# Block connection to Wifi network by MAC address, not by SSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac-address, hotspot

The only questions similar to this I've seen related to routers, and I want to accomplish this just on my wireless card, an Intel Dual-Band 8260.

I get internet through a wifi hotspot, (xfinity hotspot) as the extant cables are too old and the landlord didn't want folks rummaging through the walls.

Xfinity broadcasts their hotspots from their customer's routers.

Connection was fine until one neighbor that broadcasts their hotspot apparently unplugged their modem but left their router running. Thus broadcasting what is known as a "Zombie" hotspot. My devices can and do connect, but can't get internet.

Using [Wirelessmon](http://wirelessmon.com/), I was able to determine that there are 6 Mac addresses *all* associated with the SSID "xfinitywifi". I was able to use Wirelessmon to connect to another one and get internet, but I would like to totally ban my card from connecting to the "Zombie" mac address.

Is there a `netsh` command or similar for blocking connection to a specific MAC address?

The closest I've found was `netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="networkSSID" networktype=infrastructure`

Unfortunately the only argument that is accepted after permission is ssid - you can't give it MAC addresses here.

Is there another method I can use to block this Zombie mac address from ever messing with my hotspot connectivity again?

OS: windows 10

Comment: Could you edit the question and add your operating system.

Comment: Oops! Windows 10. I'm open to a linux solution too though, maybe I could make it work in WSL.

Comment: I don't understand how your device even _can_ connect to somebody else's network, surely you have your own credentials?

Comment: @Noughtnaut - this is not someone else's private network; read [Xfinity WiFi Home Hotspots FAQs](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/xfinity-wifi-hotspots)